# Why fixed positioned element with lower z-index is front of relative positioned element with higher z-index?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a code which controls scroll dependant animations. The direct children of body are put on each other. So the first element has z-index 0, the second has z-index 1, and so on. And all of them are wrappers, with relative position. They children have relative position first, and if the element reaches the top of the window, the position of it switches to fixed. If it happen, it's wrapper goes back in the layer panel (with z-index: 100), behind an another element with position: fixed, and with z-index 2. It's a bit weird, because if the wrapper's child has position: relative, the wrapper takes the right place. After it's child's position turns to fixed, it immediately goes back in the layers. What's the relationship between these things? For better understanding i attach some pictures from chrome devtools, layers:
[image]
Here, the black element is the child, and the gradient element is the parent. The parent stays at the right place in the order of z axis, and the child has position: relative.
[image]
Here, just a few scrolls away, the child gains position: fixed, and the parent goes back (with z-index 100). What happens here? Why the parent goes back in the layers, if it's child has position: fixed?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Positioning/Understanding_z_index/The_stacking_context

Comment: Why don't you post the code instead of describing it? What makes you think that'll improve your chances of getting an answer?

Comment: Because in the past i posted a code which descibes the problem, but it was too long and i get downvoted. If i want to describe the problem, this code will also be too long. That's why.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve